# Counting acyclic tournaments

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So, a question on my homework asks us to count the number of acyclic tournaments on $n$ vertices. I understand what it's asking, but I don't know how to even get started. This is a combinatorics class and we haven't done a lot of graph theory so I feel kind of lost. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: A tournament is acyclic if and only if it’s transitive, which in turn is the case if and only if the score sequence (sequence of out-degrees of the vertices) is $\langle n-1,n-2,\ldots,2,1,0\rangle$. In other words, there’s a perfect ranking of the $n$ players, with an absolute winner who can beat each of the others, a second-place finisher who can beat everyone but the winner, and so on down to one who loses to everyone else.

Comment: So then would it be a matter of picking the absolute winner, then picking the second place winner, etc, down to the total loser? Essentially, $\binom{n}{1}\cdot\binom{n-1}{1}\cdots\binom{2}{1}\cdot 1 = n!$ ?

Comment: @walkar: That’s right. I don’t know how much explanation you’re required to give, so you might want to think a bit about why being acyclic is equivalent to being transitive. It’s not hard: show that if it’s transitive, it must be acyclic, and if it’s not transitive, it must contain a $3$-cycle.

Comment: Well, I think directly proving the out-degree sequence must be $<n-1,...,0>$ would be enough, but again, not only have we not done much graph theory, this is our first digraph stuff, so I'm still a little lost as to techniques for examining/proving things about digraphs. Do you have any more gentle hints? Also: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @walkar: You’re welcome. You could try induction on $n$. For the induction step start with an acyclic tournament on $n+1$ vertices and remove a vertex $v$ with minimal out-degree. By the induction hyp. what’s left has degree sequence $\langle n-1,\ldots,0\rangle$. Now put $v$ back in and show that it must have had out-degree $0$ in the original tournament, because otherwise you get a cycle.